# Double counting in temporal difference learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference

I am working on a temporal difference learning example (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrxgdpduWOU), and I'm having some trouble with the following equation in my python implementation as I seem to be double counting rewards and Q.

If I coded the grid below as a 2d array, my current location is (2, 2) and the goal is (2, 3), assuming max reward is 1. Let Q(t) be the average mean of my current location, then r(t+1) is 1 and I assume max Q(t+1) is also 1, which results in my Q(t) becoming close to 2 (assuming gamma of 1). Is this correct, or should I assume that Q(n), where n is the end point is 0?

[image]

[image: Grid]

Edited to include code - I modified the get_max_q function to return 0 if it is the end point and the values are all now below 1 (which I assume is more correct since reward is just 1) but not sure if this is the right approach (previously I set it to return 1 when it was the end point).

```
#not sure if this is correct
def get_max_q(q, pos):
    #end point 
    #not sure if I should set this to 0 or 1
    if pos == (MAX_ROWS - 1, MAX_COLS - 1):
        return 0
    return max([q[pos, am] for am in available_moves(pos)])

def learn(q, old_pos, action, reward):
    new_pos = get_new_pos(old_pos, action)
    max_q_next_move = get_max_q(q, new_pos) 

    q[(old_pos, action)] = q[old_pos, action] +  alpha * (reward + max_q_next_move - q[old_pos, action]) -0.04

def move(q, curr_pos):
    moves = available_moves(curr_pos)
    if random.random() < epsilon:
        action = random.choice(moves)
    else:
        index = np.argmax([q[m] for m in moves])
        action = moves[index]

    new_pos = get_new_pos(curr_pos, action)

    #end point
    if new_pos == (MAX_ROWS - 1, MAX_COLS - 1):
        reward = 1
    else:
        reward = 0

    learn(q, curr_pos, action, reward)
    return get_new_pos(curr_pos, action)

=======================
OUTPUT
Average value (after I set Q(end point) to 0)
defaultdict(float,
            {((0, 0), 'DOWN'): 0.5999999999999996,
             ((0, 0), 'RIGHT'): 0.5999999999999996,
              ...
             ((2, 2), 'UP'): 0.7599999999999998})

Average value (after I set Q(end point) to 1)
defaultdict(float,
        {((0, 0), 'DOWN'): 1.5999999999999996,
         ((0, 0), 'RIGHT'): 1.5999999999999996,
         ....
         ((2, 2), 'LEFT'): 1.7599999999999998,
         ((2, 2), 'RIGHT'): 1.92,
         ((2, 2), 'UP'): 1.7599999999999998})
```

Comment: Show your code, show your desired output, and show the incorrect output that you're getting instead.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you and I have included my code and output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Q value represents an estimate of how much reward do ou expect to receive until the end of the episode. So, in a terminal state, maxQ = 0, because you won't receive any more rewards after then. So, the Q value at `t` will be 1, which is correct for your undiscounted problem. But you can't ignore the `gamma` in the equation, add it to your formula to make it discounted. So, for instance, if `gamma = 0.9`, the Q value at `t` will be 0.9. At (2,1) and (1,2) it will be 0.81 and so on.

Comment: Thank you, and I'll experiment with a gamma value! Thanks for the explanation, and it makes sense that maxQ is 0 in a terminal state with the way you explained.